# Export default by webpack (for aggregating modules)

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have a file `Testimonials/index.js` which is an interface of component pod.

Everything is fine, but after production build it behave like file has been omitted.

So if I add some logs like

```
import './Testimonials.less';

console.log('index File');
export { default } from './Testimonials.component';
```

I don't see that log (component is imported from `components/Testimonials` and works fine).

if I replace it with

```
import './Testimonials.less';

console.log('index File');
import Testimonials from './Testimonials.component';

export default Testimonials;
```

it works as expected

Any ideas where to dig to?

P.S. example is correct

1) it works

2) it is described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export as `Aggregating modules`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not correct way to export

```
export { default } from './Testimonials.component';
```

It's should be something like this

```
export { name1, name2, …, nameN };
```

This work perfect

```
import Testimonials from './Testimonials.component';

export default Testimonials;
```

because in your Testimonials.component already export Testimonials variable so you can import like that

`export default` is the keyword of js

Comment: It's correct way, which is described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export  (// Aggregating modules)